# User space defined file descriptor (Linux)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, file-descriptor

Is it possible (specifically in Linux) to make a file descriptor from user-provided functions like the following?

```
ssize_t (*write)(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
ssize_t (*read)(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
```

(and maybe some more functions, like `close()` and/or something for polling)

It should look for the OS as a normal FD number, but be handled by the user-provided callbacks (as above) rather than by the OS itself.

The reason why I ask is to know whether it is possible to implement this feature suggestion in user-space (e.g. in Glibc) without modifying the kernel: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=135401

Comment: Check out [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace)