# Equivalent of fopencookie for unix file descriptor

Tags: c, linux, unix, posix

The glibc-specific `fopencookie` call allows the programmer to define a set of callbacks which will provide the functionalities for I/O of a `FILE`object.

I would like to get the same kind of logic (defining callbacks etc) for a regular file descriptor, as I would do in the Linux kernel with character devices (`struct file_operations` and such), but in userspace. This does not specifically need to be bound to an actual file.

Is there anything like that in Posix, or even in some ${some}libc-specific way?

Comment: Duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38467736/user-space-defined-file-descriptor-linux?rq=1. I can't flag as duplicated, since it does not have answers.

Comment: did you tried `fuse` ?

Comment: No, but it's not what I aim at… what I really want is a file which is filesystem independent, more like a socket, really. But I guess I can actually use a socket, and read data from it. It will just give me more buffer copying around than implementing a syscall, so to say